# Math 110C, Multivariable Calculus, Absolute Max and Min for 2 Variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find the absolute maximum and minimum values of $f$ on the set $D$, where $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2x$, and $D$ is the closed triangular region with vertices $(2,0),(0,2),$ and $(0,-2)$.

---

First, I found the first partial derivatives to get the critical points:

$f_x=2x-2$ and $f_y=2y$

Then I got $0=2x-2\implies 0=x-1\implies x=1$ and $0=2y\implies 0=y$ giving C.P. $(1,0)$.

Next, I found the second partial derivatives and put this information into the Second Derivatives Test:

$f_{xx}=2$ and $f_{xy}=0$ and $f_{yy}=2$

$D(x,y)=(2)(2)-(0)^2=4-0=4$

Then, I checked the C.P.:

$f(1,0)=1+0-2=-1: D(1,0)=4$ and $f_{xx}=2$ so local minimum.

How do I check for local maximum and local minimum with the vertices $(2,0),(0,2),$ and $(0,-2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the partial derivatives of $f$ only vanish at $(1,0)$, you can compute the max  $f$ on the boundary of the triangle (which is a single variable problem). And this max is the maximum of $f$. The minimum of $f$ is $f(1,0)=-1$.

Or you can view $f(x)=(x-1)^{2}+y^2-1$, so  $f(x,y)$ represents  (distance from $(x,y)$ to $(1,0)) ^2-1 $). So you can see from the picture what the min and max are

Comment: What do you mean by vanish? Could you explain that? Also, how would I compute the max  on the boundary of the triangle? I am not really getting that?

Comment: Vanish=equal to 0.  The triangle has three edges. For example, one edge is $y=-x+2$ where $0\leq x\leq 2$, then $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2x=x^2+(-2+x)^2-2x$

Comment: If $f$ has a minimum or maximum in the interior, then at that point $f_x$ and $f_y$ must be both $0$ . So maximum can only happen on the boundary

Comment: so basically you just know the vertexes are maximums?